# Docker (GitLab CI local runner): "Mounts denied"

Tags: docker, go, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using GitLab CI, and the excellent [local GitLab CI runner](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/312) for testing stages before pushing them using the `docker exec` method.

I use Golang as my language of choice and recently moved my `$GOPATH` from `~/go` to `/go`, as per the official recommendations.

However, now when I try to test my builds, I get this error message:

```
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Error response from daemon: Mounts denied:
The path /go/src/[redacted] is not shared from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing.
```

Moving the code back to a folder under my home directory, it works again. Attempting the fix in the message gives another error:

```
rm: cannot remove ‘rm: cannot remove '/go/src/[redacted]': Read-only file system
```

It's trying to remove the current, local working directory (which is my actual repository, so I obviously do not want that).

What is the proper way to configure Docker (or the runner) to be able to work inside my `$GOPATH`?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are the filesystem rights the same between `~/go` and `/go`? Does the user running the runner process have enough rights to read `/go`?

Comment: Hi @jeanMarcAssin, sorry, I missed your comment! I think the runner is running as my own user, not a dedicated one, and the entire path to my code (`/go/src/.../myproj`) has `drwxr-xr-x`, so those permissions shouldn't be a problem?